# How to set this.class to do something?

Tags: jquery

How to set this.class to do something?
Now this.block doesn't work!

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="block" >#Product 01.</div>
    <img src="001.jpg" width="300"/>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="block" >#Product 02.</div>
    <img src="002.jpg" width="300"/>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(".container").click(showDescription);

function showDescription() {
      $(this.block).slideToggle("slow");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `find()` to locate the element with class `block`:

```
$(this).find(".block").slideToggle("slow");
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried `$(this).find('#block').slideToggle("slow");` ?

Answer (score 0):

Your js can be like this

```
$(".container").click(showDescription);

function showDescription() {
      $(this).find('div.block').slideToggle("slow");
}
```

and it will work.